# My Angular directive is not getting data from controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have this controller

```
  .controller('Main', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.uiState = {'name': 'test'};
  }])
```

and directive is like this

```
      scope: {uiState: '='},
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
console.log(scope.uiState) // coming as undefined

}
```

I am using like this

```
<my-dir uiState="uiState"> </my-dir>
```

I think my directive is getting compiled before the controller populates that data.

Any ideas

I now see that i have this error in firebug

```
Error: [$compile:nonassign] Expression 'undefined' used with directive 'my-dir' is non-assignable!
```

Comment: you can have a watch to the property

Comment: @ArunPJohny I have many properties like that. Is there any way without watch

Comment: I don't think other than watch there is a way

Comment: @ArunPJohny , is there any difference between `uiState="uiState"` and `uistate="uiState"` because first one is not working and second one works in watch. all lower case characters work but if use some camel case then it don't work

Comment: @ArunPJohny even if i use same key like camelcase then it dont work, i had to use all lower cases for attribute names in directives. was that a requirement for directive attributes?

Comment: you are right - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/CNNRp/10/ - Looks like the camel cased scope properties are also processed differently by ng

Answer (score 0):

Did you try: scope: {uiState: '=uiState'}?

Answer (score 0):

Here your controller is not at all invoked. For invocation to happen, there must be at least one element with ng-controller. you can change it as,

```
<my-dir uiState="uiState" ng-controller="Main"> </my-dir>
```

Comment: my main controller is at the top and that controller is not the directive controller